# In ESB How to check if a key exists in json response

Tags: json, esb, wso2-esb

I'm new to ESB proxy services, 
I'm getting JSON response from a Google service, I need to check if a specific key exists in the response, i.e. In the following json,
`{
  "kind":"$$$$",
  "totalItems":0
  }`

I need to check if totalItems exists in the response and I want to filter this in proxy-service itself.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The following works on WSO2 EI 6.1.1. Use the filter mediator.

```
<filter xpath="//jsonObject/totalItems">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON path expression as given here. //totalItems Depending on your usecase you nay use Filter mediator with the above JSON path expression for your filter.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to assign value to a property and after that string length can be check.

```
<property expression="json-eval(json-eval($.key)" name="isDataFound"
        scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
  <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="string-length($ctx:isDataFound)>0">
        <then/>

<else/>
</filter>
```